# why do the pointers in this program refer to non related fields?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>


struct node {
int n;
int d;
struct node *ptr;
int *ec;
int *fl;
int xs;
};

// This is a structure of node of a graph

void createNode(struct node *newNode,int no,int dis)
{
newNode->n=no;
newNode->d=dis;
newNode->ptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
newNode->ec=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
newNode->fl=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
newNode->xs=(int)malloc(sizeof(int));
}

void createArr(struct node *newNode,struct node *toNode, int capt,int e_no)
{
newNode->ptr[e_no]=*toNode;
newNode->ec[e_no]=capt;
newNode->fl[e_no]=0;
newNode->xs=0;
}

void printNode(struct node *newNode,int e)
{
printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",newNode->n,(newNode->ptr[e]).n,newNode->ec[e],
newNode->d,newNode->fl[e],newNode->xs);
}

int main()
{

// Assigning memory to nodes


struct node *newNode1 =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *newNode2 =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *newNode3 =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
struct node *newNode4 =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

// This function call allocates memory to arrays inside structure node

createNode(newNode1,1,4);
createNode(newNode2,2,0);
createNode(newNode3,3,0);
createNode(newNode4,4,0);

// This function call forms edges between nodes, sets capacity of edges, flow of edges, excess at each node

createArr(newNode1,newNode2,1,1);
createArr(newNode1,newNode4,2,2);
createArr(newNode2,newNode3,3,1);
createArr(newNode4,newNode2,5,1);
createArr(newNode4,newNode3,5,2);

// This function call prints the node

printNode(newNode1,1);
printNode(newNode1,2);
printNode(newNode2,1);
printNode(newNode4,1);
printNode(newNode4,2);
return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1   2   1   4   0   0
1   4   2   4   0   0
2   3   3   0   0   0
4   2   5   0   0   0
4   3   5   0   0   0
```

If I change input like this

```
/*only this part changed, rest input through main() same*/ 

createNode(newNode1,1,4);
createNode(newNode2,2,1);
createNode(newNode3,3,2);
createNode(newNode4,4,3);
```

**output:**

```
1   2   1   4   3   0
1   4   2   4   0   0
2   3   3   1   0   0
4   2   5   3   2   0
4   3   5   3   0   0
```

Why is 'fl' of node 1 getting value of 'd' of node4, even if both are not related and I have explicitly made 'fl' of every node 0 ?

Comment: Does this (`newNode->ptr[e_no]=*toNode;`) seem correct given that you did this (`newNode->ptr=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node))`)?

Comment: It has an array out-of-range access. UB.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe because this instructions from createArr:

```
newNode->ec[e_no]=capt;
newNode->fl[e_no]=0;
```

are writting to undesired addresses in memory. This is what you do to initialize fields fl and ec:

```
newNode->ec=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
newNode->fl=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

So, you are reserving memory for **ONE** `int` to be pointed by `fl`, and **ONE** int to be pointed by `ec`. But when calling `createArray()`, the argument `e_no` is 1 or 2 in your examples. That is trying to write a value 1 or 2 positions past the number of ints reserved. In fact, with your current initialization, the only valid value for `e_no` should be 0.

So you have to reserve as much ints as you need, based upon the maximum value `e_no` can have.

```
newNode->ec=malloc(MAX_ENO * sizeof newNode->ec);
newNode->fl=malloc(MAX_ENO * sizeof newNode->fl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your allocation to `fl` in `createNode()` is not appropriate.

You allocate it as

```
newNode->fl=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

and assign the values in `createArr()` as

```
 newNode->fl[e_no]=0;
```

So when you do

```
createArr(newNode1,newNode2,1,1);
createArr(newNode1,newNode4,2,2);
```

it actually tries to do `newNode->fl[1] = 0` or `newNode->fl[2]=0`. But `fl` is allocated for only one element, which is accessible as `newNode->fl[0]`.

So your referencing for `fl` is not correct, that might be causing you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has undefined behavior and memory leaks all over the place. First and foremost, this line in `createNode()` is probably not what you want:

```
newNode->xs=(int)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

The size of an integer is not guaranteed to be large enough to hold an address. If this is what you really want, you should use `uintptr_t` instead.

`createArr()` accesses invalid positions everytime `e_no > 0`, because you only allocated space for one int. Thus, your program invokes undefined behavior in these lines. It also leaks memory in `newNode->xs=0;`, after that, you lost reference to the previously allocated memory in `createNode()`. I didn't get the purpose of `xs`...

Since this is undefined behavior, your program can really do anything, from crashing, to working as expected, or any other weird behavior. Fix these errors, and you will probably get what you were expecting.

Comment: i am gonna use dat 'xs' variable for later part of my program.